# Repeated consecutive values above a threshold

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, counting

I would like to know if a list has repeated consecutive values above a threshold. Lets say for this example the threshold is 5.

```
list={0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 6, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4, 6, 2, 7, 6, 5, 3, 5, 4, 5, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 0, 1, 2}
```

because of the run `6, 7, 6,` and `7, 6,`the function should return `True` or `1` or some indication that consecutive values in the list are above the threshold.

If the threshold is 6 the function would yield `False` or `0` as there are no consecutive values above 6.

This code fails

```
Select[Split[list], First[#] > 5 && Length[#] > 1 &, Infinity]
```

The Split only works for consecutive values of the same value where I need it to split for consecutive values above a threshold.

I tried SplitBy but my pattern is incorrect.

```
SplitBy[list, Repeated[#] > 5 &]
```

I understand that neither of these functions above will give `True` or `1` but once the pattern is correct, taking it to the `True` or `1` is easy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fundamental operation:

```
t = 5;        
us = UnitStep[list - (t+1)];

(* {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, \
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

Then look for sequential ones by any method:

```
us*list // Differences // FreeQ[1] // Not

MatchQ[us, {___, 1, 1, ___}]

Max @ ListConvolve[{1, 1}, us] > 1
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'm so grateful.  I would have never approached the problem in this way.   I was killing myself on finding the correct pattern.

Comment: you could directly use `MatchQ` on the list as `MatchQ[list, {___, x_Integer /; x > #, y_Integer /; y > #, ___}] &@5`  (I guess the above performs better though)

Comment: I think `Clip[list, {t+1, t}, {0, 1}]` is slightly faster than UnitStep[list - (t+1)].

Comment: @CarlWoll I don't believe that I was aware that in the second parameter of `Clip` *min* could be larger than *max*.  However on my system `UnitStep` is several times faster than your `Clip` expression.

Answer (score 1):

For short lists we could also use `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
f = DeleteCases[{_}] @ SequenceSplit[# - (th + 1), {_?Negative}] != {} &;

th = 5;
```

No repetitions above `th`

```
list = {6, 0, 0, 5, 5, 8, 0, 6};

f @ list

(* False *)
```

Repetition(s) above `th`

```
list = {6, 0, 0, 6, 6, 5, 5, 8, 0, 6};

f @ list

(* True *)
```

`SequenceSplit` is, however, much slower than the accepted answer

```
list = RandomInteger[{0, 7}, 10^6];

f @ list // RepeatedTiming
```

{1.445, True}

```
UnitStep[list - (th + 1)] // Differences // FreeQ[1] // Not // RepeatedTiming
```

{0.008, True}

Comment: I tried to look for a faster alternative than the accepted one, but I definitely couldn't think of anything better. Hopefully soon the Wolfram developers will improve the speed of the functions dedicated to sequences, since they are more practical and flexible.

Comment: Yes, many functions have become much faster over the years. In the meanwhile I use the very nice and readable sequence-functions for short lists.

Answer (score 1):

Grabbing the @eldo's examples, a faster version using `Split` is as follows:

```
list1 = {6, 0, 0, 5, 5, 8, 0, 6};
list2 = {6, 0, 0, 6, 6, 5, 5, 8, 0, 6};
list3 = RandomInteger[{0, 7}, 10^6];

f[list_, th_] := Module[{sp, pos},
sp = Split[list];
pos = First@FirstPosition[{_, __}]@Reverse@sp;
Length@Catenate@DeleteCases[{_}]@sp[[;; pos]] > th]

f[list1, 5]

(*False*)

f[list2, 5]

(*True*)

f[list3, 5] // RepeatedTiming

(*{0.347102, True}*)
```